# How do I do sort based on specific position within an Array with MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, database-administration

My usecase is this:

I have a collection of People who want to move to certain cities:

```
People {
  cities: ['London', 'Denver', 'Tokyo']
}
```

The order of the cities tells me which city they prefer the most to least. The above person prefers to be in London the most.

I have a Landlord who has houses to rent out. And this guy is from one city, say `London`.

I have this Landlord in hand and I want to query the People collection and get back all the People in order of how much they prefer the landLord's city. So for this Landlord, everyone who prefers London the most should show up first, followed by everyone who like London second-best, etc.

For a different Landlord, say one from `Denver`, the sort would change to give people who like `Denver` the most.

Any way to do this in Mongo itself?

Comment: are their only three cities per person or can that number be dynamic?

Comment: @inspired Hi, sorry for the late reply. The number can be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the way your DB is set up now, I think the best you could do is query based on the 1st item in the Array. So the landlord will pass his location (London in this example) to this method call.

```
// As an example
db.people.find({ "cities.0" : "London" })
```

Comment: but that only searches for People who have London as their first preference. I want all People who have London somewhere on the list but I want them ordered in whatever position they have London.